# Generating binary time series data for more number of base strings

Tags: c

I am trying to find Hamming distance between base strings. The state of the node S_{i} in the base strings are in the form of binary data. The code below generates 14 snapshots of data at time instants t0 - t14. How I can generate the data, for 200 no.of base strings in C so that I can get more no of data points.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>  

int main()
{

    FILE *bp = NULL;
    bp = fopen("hamming.txt","w");
    if(bp == NULL)
    printf("Error!\n");
    FILE *pr = NULL;
    pr = fopen("pairs.txt","w");
    if(pr == NULL)
    printf("Error in opening file pr!\n");
    else


        srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
        int M = RAND_MAX / 2;
        int N = 8; // No.of nodes in the network : // test run for 14 strings:
        int n = 10; // snapshots of data:
        int s[N], ss[N-1];
        double t = 0.0;
        double dt = 1;
        double delta = 0.42857;
        fprintf(bp,"s[i]\t s[i+1] \t s[i+2]\t s[i+3]\t s[i+4]\t s[i+5]
        \tpairs\t time \t\n");
        fprintf(bp,"----------------------------------------------------\n");
        for(t=0;t < n-1; )
        {
         for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
         {

             if(rand() > M)
             s[i] = 1;
             else
             s[i] = 0;

        }
       for(int i=0, j=0; i<N-1; i++)
       {
        if(!s[i])
        {
         if(s[i+1])
          {              
           if(s[i+2])    
           {
            if(s[i+3])
            {
             if(s[i+4])
             {
              if(s[i+5])
               {

                    ss[j] = 1;

               }
               else
               { 
                   ss[j] = 0;}
                   j++;

                } 

               }

              }
             }
          }  
          if(s[i])
          {
           if(!s[i+1])
           {
             if(!s[i+2])
             {
             if(!s[i+3])
             {
              if(!s[i+4])
              {
               if(!s[i+5])  
               {
                   ss[j] = 0;
               }
               else
               { 

                   ss[j] = -1;
                }
                  j++;

                 }
                }
               }
             }

           }
          if(s[i])
          {
           if(s[i+1])
            {
             if(s[i+2])
              {
               if(s[i+3])
                {
                  if(s[i+4])
                  {
                   if(s[i+5])
                   {
                        ss[j] = -1;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                      ss[j] = 0;
                   }
                      j++;
                   } 
                  }
                 }
               }
            }
           //choose only the pairs "00" and "01":
           if(s[i] == 0 && s[i+1] == 0)
           {
             //if(s[i] == 0 && s[i+2] == 1){
             fprintf(pr,"(%d%d)\t\t%0.1lf\n",s[i+1],s[i],t);
           }
           fprintf(bp,"%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d%d\t
           %0.1lf\t\n",s[i],s[i+1],s[i+2],s[i+3],s[i+4],s[i+5],s[i],s[i+1],t);
           t = t+dt;
           j++;


           }       

         }

       return 0; 
       fclose(bp);
       fclose(pr);


}
```

Comment: The formatting of our program is a total mess. Fix this please.

Comment: Solved the above question. Just need to increase N and I didnt notice this.

Comment: 1. The lots of nested `if`s are really hard to read - especially in combination with this bad formatting. Did you already think about `&&` (to reduce the number of nested `if`s)? 2. Did you realize that the first `else` in your `main()` concerns only the one statement `srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));`? The formatting might you let believe something different but the C compiler ignores formatting completely. (It's not like in Python).